# laravel 5.5 not loading jquery/vuejs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I just recently installed laravel 5.5. I'm going to use VueJS but everytime I load a page my VueJS isn't working. Probaly because of the fact that jquery isn't loaded.

I'm also using twitter bootstrap which is also not being loaded. Only the sass files are loaded. If I use a CDN for jquery and bootstrap they are working fine. But still VueJS isn't working.

I have npm up and running and I don't get any errors when compiling(npm run watch or npm run dev).

My app.js loads:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

If I try to console.log anything in this file it is also not showing anything in my console what is really strange.

In my bootstrap.js there are also the following two lines:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');
```

In my console I only see the following warning which I think comes from a plugin I use (ghostery).

```
loading pref showConsoleLogs before prefs were initialised, you will not get the correct result
```

I also saw people for who the following worked(They put this in their webpack mix):

```
mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery',"jQuery","window.$","jquery","window.jquery"]
});
```

If I add the following code to the app.js it's also not showing but it is in the file that is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Still no responses back on this thread but what have I found out so far:
 - Anything I put in my public/js/app.js doesn't get loaded. When I load the page I see the js file is loaded. I can view the contents and my contents are there but it just doesn't work.
 - I've loaded jquery through cdn because I can't get the normal jquery which should be included in my app.js through bootstrap.js

**SOLUTION: GOING BACK TO AN OLDER VERSION OF LARAVEL**

Comment: did you run `npm install && npm run dev`?

Comment: Yes I did run those both

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? The contents of `public` get created when do `yarn run dev` for dev or `yarn run prod` for production.
In essence, everything you want loaded should be loaded via webpack. If you open `webpack.mix.js` you will see everything gets mixed into `public` ref: [read more...](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix)

Answer (score 0):

After running `npm install && npm run dev`, to be sure that this is not a problem of your browser caching the previous rendered code, try running `php artisan serve`. Follow the link and if you are able to see the content you are expecting, it means your browser is caching the rendered app.js files. In that case go to your browser tools, clear its cache and then refresh the page. You may also open up the page in an incognito window.